# setting UniqueIdentifier from Guid in LINQ, Null Reference exception

Tags: c#, linq, guid, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to set a unique identifier in my customer table from the unique identifer from my membership table (asp.net membership).

However I am getting a null reference exception when doing so. This is the code.

```
 Customer customer = db.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == Convert.ToInt32(formValues["CustomerId"]));
 Guid userId = new Guid(user.ProviderUserKey.ToString());
 customer.UserId = userId;
```

It crashes on the last line.

I have tried different settings in my Customer table on the database and in the LINQ to SQL model but I keep getting this.

Anyone know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing this because this expression:

```
db.Customers.SingleOrDefault(
    c => c.Id == Convert.ToInt32(formValues["CustomerId"]));
```

is returning `null` and that `null` is being assigned to the `customer` variable.  When you use `customer` two lines later it is throwing the `NullReferenceException`.

The best thing to do here is to debug this code and see what `formValues["CustomerId"]` is set to - most likely this value is *not* set which is causing you to look up a customer in the database for a CustomerId that doesn't exist.

Comment: +1 yup - basic principle of defensive programming: if anything can return NULL (and .SingleOrDefault() definitely can!), you must **ALWAYS** check for NULL !

Comment: I feel silly :( I had the customer Id as a hidden field but it wasn't within the Begin Form using block. Anyway thanks.